# Sharepoint 2010 Calendar View in Custom List Expand All by Default

Tags: javascript, calendar, custom-list

For some reason the scripts I have found on the web (ie: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-GB/sharepoint2010general/thread/a24da49a-7fc8-47c6-a125-95e4a5b2d095) are not working with a calendar view in a custom list.

All I want to do is auto-expand all in my view when the page loads with some javascript in a CEWP.

Any thoughts or examples of how this has worked?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After SP1 for SharePoint 2010 some calendar scripts may stop working. We are using this script to determine when calendar loaded (it includes your expand all requirement):

```
_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push('WaitForCalendarToLoad');

function WaitForCalendarToLoad() {

    if (typeof SP.UI.ApplicationPages.CalendarNotify.$4a == 'undefined') {
        // post SP1
        var pwold$4b = SP.UI.ApplicationPages.CalendarNotify.$4b;
        SP.UI.ApplicationPages.CalendarNotify.$4b = function () {
            pwold$4b();
            ColourCalendar();
        }
    }
    else {
        // pre SP1
        var pwold$4a = SP.UI.ApplicationPages.CalendarNotify.$4a;
        SP.UI.ApplicationPages.CalendarNotify.$4a = function () {
            pwold$4a();
            ColourCalendar();
        }
    }
} 
function ColourCalendar() {     
    SP.UI.ApplicationPages.CalendarInstanceRepository.firstInstance().expandAll();   
}
```

It works for me on December 2011 CU.

Comment: Totally forgot to say this worked! Thanks a TON!!!!!!!

Comment: Where would you run the script?

Comment: Great solution. One question, how would you terminate the CalendarNotify event?
I am doing some coloring after the calendar loads, but cannot get the "Loading Calendar..." DIV do disapear. Thanks
Darrell

Comment: This worked GREAT! Thanks for posting, it saved the day for me.

Comment: It worked but when i'm on a list and i click item or list it just keeps showing loading... and doesn't stop.
Cheers